# Preventing users navigating to a document

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a folder in my website which contains another folder which contains many folders which all contain various documents: pdfs, word documents, txt files, excel documents, images etc.  I want to prevent users from navigating to any of these documents via the browser.  How can I do this?  I am using MVC3.

Comment: Which version of IIS?  Just turn off directory browsing

Comment: 7 I believe.  Turn off directory browsing?  I'll look into it.  Problem is locally I'm using Casini, which will make such a thing a little hard to test.  I was thinking of something more at the code/config level.  Can you turn off directory browsing from the Web.config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could move your directory structure inside the `App_Data` special folder. This folder is not directly accessible. Then simply write a controller action which given an id will stream the file to the client. Then decorate the controller action with the Authorize attribute to ensure that only authenticated users can access them.

Answer (score 1):

Directory Browsing will only prevent users from seeing the list of documents inside the folder but it won't prevent a user from entering a valid URL pointing to an existing document and seeing it. If that's what you need, you need to deny access to all users to that folder.

```
<location path="folder">
<system.web>
<authorization>
  <deny users="*"/> 
</authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't do it in IIS easily then do it in Web.config, here you go:

```
<configuration>
  <location path="Secured">
    <system.webServer>
      <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

[EDIT]

I see you want to make the contents inaccessible and not just prevent the directory listing.
In that case do the additional steps in the Icarus' answer.